# End-to-end encrypted static website content

Tags: encryption, web

I have a really simple static webpage which just consists of a single `html` file that gets served.

I want to encrypt some of its content so it can only be read by certain persons (the ones that know a certain passphrase). Please note I don't want to encrypt the source code. Just a "secret" content inside of it.

For instance:

```
<p>
This is a secret message
</p>
```

I know I can add authentication at a server level, but I don't want my `html` file to be even readable by the server, meaning I want end-to-end encryption of the "secret" parts.

This might be a good job for asymmetric encryption. I could use the others public keys to encrypt the message so only them will be able to read it (I even thought of mutual SSL authentication).

The thing is, this might be too difficult/not possible to do for the intended recipients as they're non-technical people. I just want them to use a passphrase to see the "secret" content, not installing any certificates or similar stuff. So maybe just symmetric encryption is a better fit.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this? Is AES or a similar algorithm a good idea for this?

I'm open to different approaches.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this client-side (in browser) using javascript using the Web Crypto API (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).  The user would enter the passphrase, an AES key would be derived from the passphrase using a KDF, then the key would be used to decrypt the ciphertext via AES and write the plaintext to a DOM element on the page.

Comment: Basically you answered part of your question, with a single password for static content you need to use a symmetric cipher (AES as the most common). `Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this? ` This is really not any specific question. Yes we know how to achieve this. But what are you struggling with? What is blocking for you?

Answer (score 0):

See the example below, where a static HTML page contains some encrypted ciphertext embedded in the page source.  The user can enter an AES256 key to decrypt the ciphertext, and upon decryption (assuming the correct key was entered) the plaintext is displayed.

As you can see, all of the crypto is done client-side (in browser) in javascript using the window.crypto.subtle.decrypt() function from the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).

The key to decrypt the ciphertext is:
ae35b7091804f9a011fd7e2ec030cf78e0aadf225d86a7238cfd73a451cbdb86

---

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AES Decryption</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>AES Decryption</h2>
        <p>Enter key: <input id=txtkeyhex size=64 maxlength=64 value=''> (32 bytes, hex-encoded)</p>
        <p><button id=btndecrypt onclick=javascript:fdecrypt();>Decrypt</button></p>
        <p> </p>
        <p><div id=divdecryptresult style="font-family:courier;"></p>

        <script>
            async function fdecrypt() { 
                var ciphertexthex='13d9858cf68ca674d91bbbd23e2907b5d079e0718c14506f95d44cbd79d8808c76b863a431138f2ed2e7277b166f898f56c3311baffa5013fea2fe93bc1e33ceaa5a97b885d4e724422bf8987b416ece84cacf511136d5ee545826f7f15ee93f';
                var ivhex='6bf8762dc343afc9a7f02d1a6af75d28';

                if(!ishex(txtkeyhex.value)) {
                    alert('decryption key must be hex-encoded.');
                    return;
                }
                if(txtkeyhex.value.length!=64) {
                    alert('invalid length for decryption key.  key must be 32 bytes in length.  (32 bytes = 64 hexadecimal characters)');
                    return;
                }

                var ciphertextbytes=hextobytes(ciphertexthex);
                var keybytes=hextobytes(txtkeyhex.value);
                var ivbytes=hextobytes(ivhex);

                var key=await window.crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', keybytes, {name: 'AES-CBC', length: 256}, false, ['decrypt']) 
                .catch(function(err){
                    alert('unable to import key.');
                    console.error(err);
                });
                if(!key) { return; }

                var plaintextbytes=await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "AES-CBC", iv: ivbytes}, key, ciphertextbytes)
                .catch(function(err){
                    alert('decryption failed.  check inputs.');
                    console.error(err);
                });
                if(!plaintextbytes) { return; }

                var plaintext=new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(plaintextbytes);
                divdecryptresult.innerText=plaintext;
            }

            function ishex(s) {
                var regex=/[0-9A-Fa-f]/g;
                return regex.test(s);
            }

            function hextobytes(hexstring) {
                var result=new Uint8Array(hexstring.length/2);
                for(var i=0; i<hexstring.length/2; i++) {
                    result[i]=parseInt(hexstring.substring(i*2, i*2+2), 16);
                }
                return result;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use staticrypt (https://github.com/robinmoisson/staticrypt).

This also shows a password prompt to the user and manages "remember password" through cookies.